# How to resolve error " A setup package missing or damaged " while installing Visual studio 2015 on Windows 8.1 please help me to resolve this problem

Tags: visual-studio-2015

How to resolve error " A setup package missing or damaged " while installing Visual studio 2015 on Windows 8.1
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tesA4.jpg)